# AspNetCore / SignalR - Returning HttpResponseMessage from SignalR Hub Server results in InvalidDataException

Tags: signalr, httpresponsemessage

I have two web applications.
From one web application, I am trying to communicate with the other application via SignalR.
I am sending data via SignalR using InvokeAsync and waiting for a result on the client.
On the server, with the data sent, I am calling a web api and then I want to send the result as HttpResponseMessage to the SignalR client which is waiting.
But when trying to do so, I get the following error :

```html
{System.IO.InvalidDataException: Connection terminated while reading a message.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.ReceiveLoop(ConnectionState connectionState)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.InvokeCoreAsyncCore(String methodName, Type returnType, Object[] args, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.InvokeCoreAsync(String methodName, Type returnType, Object[] args, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnectionExtensions.InvokeCoreAsync[TResult](HubConnection hubConnection, String methodName, Object[] args, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at SecretariatMedical.Services.WebService.LogInAndGetToken(LoginViewModel loginViewModel) in C:\Users\SylvainB\Desktop\aspnetcore\Projet Clinique Charles\SecretariatMedical\SecretariatMedical\Services\WebService.cs:line 82}
```

Here is the code from the client :

```html
connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl("https://localhost:44379/ServeurWebServiceSignalRHub")
            .Build();

connection.Closed += async (error) =>
{
    await Task.Delay(new Random().Next(0, 5) * 1000);
    await connection.StartAsync();
};
            

await connection.StartAsync();
                    
HttpResponseMessage responseSignalR = await connection.InvokeAsync<HttpResponseMessage>("LogInAndGetToken", loginViewModel );
```

The code on the SignalR Hub Server :

```html
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> LogInAndGetToken(LoginViewModel loginViewModel)
        {
            try
            {
                string apiUrl = "api/authenticationapi/gettoken";
                HttpResponseMessage response;
                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44379");
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                    response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(apiUrl, loginViewModel);
                    //ResultLoginViewModel resultLogin = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ResultLoginViewModel>();

                    return response;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                HttpResponseMessage responseError = new     HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
                return responseError;
            }
           
        }
```

The code in my StartUp.cs :

```html
services.AddSignalR().AddJsonProtocol(options => 
            {
                options.PayloadSerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
            });
```

On the SignalR Hub Server, when I try to read the data and send it back as an object ViewModel, the SignalR Client receives it normally.

Does anybody know why there is a problem with transporting a HttpResponseMessage ?

Thanks a lot for your help.